# The cin.ignore removing first character the second time function is being called

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this? Without cin.ignore, the getline would not work, and after the first time when I call the function again, the first character is removed. So far I have tried using stringstream instead of getline, cin.sync(), cin.clear(), but nothing seems to work. Also the reason why I am using getline, is because some streets have spaces between them, so simply using cin would not work in this case

```
std::cout <<  "Enter Street Name 1: " ;
std::cin.ignore(1,EOF);
std::getline(std::cin,s1);
std::cout <<  "Enter Street Name 2: " ;
std::getline(std::cin,s2);
std::cout<<"Your first street was: "<<s1<<" Your second street was: "<<s2 <<". Please look at the map to find the intersection of " << s1 << " and " << s2 <<std::endl;
```

Output

```
Enter Street Name 1: Bloor
Enter Street Name 2: Yonge
Your first street was: Bloor Your second street was: Yonge. Please look at the map to find the intersection of Bloor and Yonge
Enter Street Name 1: Bloor
Enter Street Name 2: Yonge
Your first street was: loor Your second street was: Yonge. Please look at the map to find the intersection of loor and Yonge
Enter Street Name 1: Bloor
Enter Street Name 2: Uong
Your first street was: loor Your second street was: Uong. Please look at the map to find the intersection of loor and Uong
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's especially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Please don't post a link to a picture of the code. Post the code here.

Comment: Changed it to code

Comment: General rule of thumb: If you have to `ignore`, `ignore` after the operation that leaves data that must be ignored in the stream. If you `ignore` before a future operation on the off chance there is data that must be ignored,odds are good the the program will `ignore` something you did not wish to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

> Without `cin.ignore`, the `getline` would not work,

That is true only if there is some code before that that leaves a newline character in the input stream.

> and after the first time when I call the function again, the first character is removed.

That makes sense. `cin.ignore()` reads and discards one character.

I am not able to suggest something that will fix your problem without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

because you use cin.ignore() without parameters which means ignore the next char in the buffer that's why the first character is removed. To use cin.ignore()

cin.ignore( int nCount = 1, int delim = EOF );

Parameters

nCount - The maximum number of characters to extract.

delim - The delimiter character (defaults to EOF).

example
`std::cin.ignore(256,' ');`   // ignore until space

Comment: I tried doing std::cin.ignore(1,EOF) and it still does not work

Comment: try to use cin.ignore after getline not befre

Comment: Problem with that is, then the second getline would not work, and the output is completely messed up.